# "to be" or "to be in"... which one should I use?

Tags: word-in-context

Assuming the sentence below makes any sense (which I'm not sure about) would I have to include the preposition "in" after the verb "to be" at the end or is it not necessary?

> And therefore, because of her mother’s illness, she was forced to live
>   years and years in a place where she could no longer stand to be / to be in.

Comment: The final *in* is redundant with the relative conjunction *where*, which itself has the connotation of being in some place. The sentence seems clear: she felt compelled to nurse her sick mother for a long time, which required her to stay where she didn't want to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and clarifications.